# How to send reply message to Slack with GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, slack

First of all,I'm not native English speaker.So,I'm sorry if there are some mistake in English.

I want to make the Chat-Bot which work-flow is below.

1. send message from Slack
2. add the message to spreadsheet with GAS
3. send 'SAVED!' from GAS to Slack

to make the flow, I wrote the code below on GAS.

```
function doPost(e) {

   const webhookUrl = "Incoming-Webhook-URL";

          const payload = {
        "text":"SAVED!"
          }
      UrlFetchApp.fetch(webhookUrl,{
        'method':'post',
        'payload':JSON.stringify(payload)
      })

　
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spread-Sheet-ID');
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("シート1")
    var token = 'Outgoing-Webhook-Token' //outgoing token
    

   try{
    
// Googleスプレッドシートにデータを追加する処理
    if (token == e.parameter.token){
      
        let datetime = new Date();
        let date = (datetime.getFullYear() + '/' + ('0' + (datetime.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + ('0' + datetime.getDate()).slice(-2))
        let time = (('0' + datetime.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + datetime.getMinutes()).slice(-2));
       
        let text = e.parameter.text;
        
        array = [date,time,text];
        sheet.appendRow(array);
        
    }
     
   }catch(err){
    
     Logger.log(err)
   }
}
```

But,The Code above doesn't send the message "SAVED!" to Slack.
On the other hand,The message is send when I push the execution button on GAS.

I can't understand why this differ is occured. Can anyone explain the reason about this please? Thank's.

Comment: Can you confirm that this script was triggered when you sent a message to the slack bot?

Comment: @CharlesHan Thank you for comments! Yes,I can confirm about that. The message send from slack is written in certain spread-sheet row.